# c# xaml string to button name

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I want to random choose color of Button.
It works when I do `Change_color(But0_0)`.
But i want to make it work automatically using function `for`.
But this is not working (stop the program).

```
private void But0_0_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 1; i <= 20; i++)
    {
        var ele = MainGrid.FindName("But0_" + i);
        Button button = ele as Button;
        Change_color(button);
    }
    Change_color(But0_0);
}

private void Change_color(Button name)
{
    Random rand = new Random();
    Color[] colors = new Color[]
    {
        Colors.Red,
        Colors.Blue,
        Colors.Green,
    };
    name.Background= new SolidColorBrush(colors[rand.Next(0, 3)]);
}
```

Comment: After you do `Button button = ele as Button;`, let your program check whether the variable *button* is `null`. If it is null (does not contain a reference to a Button object), don't call Change_color with it. There are probably other issues with your program, but this one is a problem with the code you posted in your question.

Comment: OK it is working. But all buttons have been changed to same color. How can i change it to random change color of each one?

Comment: Debug and step through your program. Check what your But0_0_Click handler and Change_color method are really doing. Seeing it is learning about what is going on there. (As a guess, try instantiating the Random object only once, keeping it in a private field.)

Comment: Ok but when i'm doing it step by step in the end all is changed, but when i'm doing this whithout step by step- only one have been changed... WTF?

Comment: The Random() constructor takes the current time as a seed value. To understand the behavior, you need to understand that different Random objects using the same seed value produce the same pseudo-number sequence (which also means, that the 1st random number is the same). Now, Random() constructor uses only the current time with a certain, limited resolution (i can't recall what the resolution is). Now if you single-step through your program, enough time has passed between two calls of the Random() constructor so that the seed value changes even when considering the limited resolution. (1/2)

Comment: (2/2) However, if you run your program normally, your code might be executed "too fast", with only little time passing between calls of the Random() constructor (considering the limited time resolution used by the Random() constructor), essentially each time producing a Random object with the same seed number. Hence my guess/advice to only use **one** Random object and not recreate it again and again in the Change_color method. See also the remarks section in the documentation of the Random() constructor: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h343ddh9.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moving the initialization of `Random` out of your `Change_color` method should work.

```
private Random rand = new Random();
private Color[] colors = new Color[]
{
    Color.Red,
    Color.Blue,
    Color.Green
}    

private void But0_0_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{    
    for (int i = 1; i <= 20; i++)
    {
        var ele = MainGrid.FindName("But0_" + i);
        Button button = ele as Button;

        if (button != null)
        {
            Change_color(button);
        }
    }
}

private void Change_color(Button name)
{
    name.Background= new SolidColorBrush(colors[rand.Next(0, 3)]);
}
```